# How to fix imaplib returning unintelligible text (possibly base64)?

Tags: python-2.7, imaplib

I am working to be able to pull the bodies of emails to be use later in my program where I will pull specific pieces of the text. The code so far works with emails sent from a gmail account to another gmail account but returns a bunch of strange text when trying to read an email sent from an outlook inbox.

I have tried decoding it from base64 but it doesn't seem to help.

```
 import imaplib
 import email

 username = "XXXX"
 password = "YYYY"

 imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)    
 imap.login(username, password)
 imap.select('INBOX')


 status, response = imap.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
 unreadmsgs = response[0].split()

 result, data = imap.fetch(unreadmsgs[0], "(UID BODY[TEXT])")

 raw_mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
 raw2= raw_mail.get_payload(decode=True)
 print(raw2)
```

This returns something like below when I am instead looking for readable text.

`--_000_VI1PR07MB3966DEECC2518D0D5C2C2EF6C4850VI1PR07MB3966eurp_
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`
`DQoNCkZyb206IFBlYWNlVGVjaCBBY2NlbGVyYXRvciA8ZGltaXRyYS5oYXR6dWRpc0BjNWNhcGl0YWwuY29tPg0KU2VudDogTW9uZGF5LCBKYW51YXJ5IDcsIDIwMTkgMTE6NDMgUE0NClRvOiBEaW1pdHJhIEhhdHp1ZGlzIDxEaW1pdHJhLkhhdHp1ZGlzQGM1Y2FwaXRhbC5jb20+OyBIYWRlZWwgQWwtVGFzaGkgPGhhZGVlbC5hbHRhc2hpQGM1Y2FwaXRhbC5jb20+DQpTdWJqZWN0OiBOaW5qYSBGb3JtcyBTdWJtaXNzaW9uDQoNCkNvbXBhbnkgLyBTdGFydHVwIE5hbWU6DQoNClNlbnNlIEFmcmljYQ0KDQpHaXZlIHVzIGEgc2hvcnQgZGVzY3JpcHRpb24gb2YgeW91ciBpbXBhY3QgdmVudHVyZS46DQoNCldlIGhhdmUgYSBnbG9iYWwgdmlzaW9uIG9mIHByb21vdGluZyBjaXRpemVuIHBhcnRpY2lwYXRpb24gaW4gcHVibGljIGRpc2NvdXJzZS4NClNpbmNlIG91ciBsYXVuY2ggaW4gMjAxNy8yMDE4IGluIENhbWVyb29uLCBvdXIgY29tbWl0bWVudCB0byB0aGF0IHZpc2lvbiB3YXMgaW1wbGVtZW50ZWQgYnkgbWFraW5nIGxvY2FsIG5ld3MgYW5kIG90aGVyIG5vbi1maWN0aW9uIG1lZGlhIG1vcmUgYWNjZXNzaWJsZS4gV2UgYXJlIG5vdyB0aGUg......`
 and so on

Comment: If attachments aren't a concern, you could fetch RFC822, and pass that through the parser.

Answer (score 0):

This is base64 encoded (see the content-tranfer-encoding above your data)

```
decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(encodedStr)
decodedStr = str(decodedBytes, "utf-8")
print(decodedStr)
```